# Automatic calcul fields don't work with iText

Tags: pdf, itext, interactive

I have an interactive pdf form that contains totals field, those fields fulfilling automatically when other fields are filled by users, and it works very well manually. but when I fill it programmatically using iText with java, the normal one fills very well but those with the automatic calculation does not work and shows zero.

```
static String book = "myForm.pdf";
static String bookstamp = "myFormTest.pdf";
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader (book); 
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper (reader, new FileOutputStream (String.format (bookstamp))); 
stamper.getAcroFields ();
stamper.setField ("ca50", "15000");
stamper.getAcroFields () ;
stamper.setField ("ca30", "150");
stamper.close ();
```

Comment: Have you got some code ?

Comment: You can edit your post. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic calculation of field values in PDFs happens by means of Javascript in the PDF. In case of certain events (e.g. value of a field changed or focus of a field lost) this Javascript is executed and sets the field value to the newly calculated one.

iText, on the other hand, does not run any Javascript. In iText only those parts of the PDF are changed which you explicitly change, side effects are not desired.

Thus, to show appropriately re-calculated fields upon opening your PDF after editing it with iText, you should also trigger the re-calculation of the fields upon opening the PDF.

If you provide the PDF file itself, you can be shown how to do that.

**PS:** You can trigger re-calculation when the document is opened by adding

```
stamper.addJavaScript("this.calculateNow();");
reader.removeUsageRights();
```

before

```
stamper.close ();
```

Unfortunately this will disable the Reader-Enabling of the document.

Comment: Ok, thank you that's very clear and logic http://www.mfdgi.gov.dz/Serie%20G%20n50%20V1.1.pdf here is the link of the pdf that i am working on.

Comment: Added some JavaScript work-around which kills Reader-Enabling, though. Is Reader-Enabling required in your use-case?

Comment: Thank you very much mkl :D it work perfectly, and no i don't need Reader-Enabling.

Comment: Great! Please be aware that other pdf processing applications without Javascript engine don't know about the calculated values.